# In javascript parsing a string gives me huge number, why?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have a string in response "2.222222522879E12",

When I do

```
parseFloat("2.222222522879E12")
2222222522879
```

But the expected value should be 2.22, 
Whats happening ?

And how can I fix it

Comment: `e` == exponential/Scientific notation

Comment: Who says it "should" be 2.22?

Comment: what is E12 in your string?.

Comment: Possible Dup of [How to convert a String containing Scientific Notation to correct Javascript number format](//stackoverflow.com/q/10943997) and [How to convert big negative scientific notation number into decimal notation string in javascript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/16139452)

Comment: Also see [How to use scientific notation in js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27151311)

Comment: You are expecting a wrong output.

Comment: Rahul are you happy with my answer? If you are please accept it

Answer (score 3):

You're going to get `2.222222522879* 10^12` with that expression as `E` means `exponent`, or `to the power of`

As per your edit asking how to fix:

use the `Number.prototype.toPrecision()` function. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision) is the documentation

Comment: Apologies for the hectic number of edits I made!